# RUN a PHP script via a .bat file with integers. ex. test.php?min=1&max=10

Tags: php, batch-file

Like the title says.

I use a bat file to run a scheduled task. I am having a hard time getting it to work when I add the Min/max at the end.

There a way to do with?

Answer (score 0):

Run the command using a syntax like

```
php test.php --min=1 --max=10
```

And use the [getopt()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php) function in your script to read the values for `max` and `min`

```
$shortopts  = "";
$longopts  = array(
    "max:",
    "min:",
);
$options = getopt($shortopts, $longopts);

var_dump($options['min'], $options['max']);
```